# Looking for an architecture for parent/child projects to avoid conflicts when merging

Tags: git, architecture, parent-child, software-design

I have an architecture defined as follows:

A project named parent which has a set of features (*feature-1, feature-2*) and another project named child which inherits from parent and which (in addition to parent's features) has the features (*feature-1, feature-2, feature-3*).

My current principle is that child is a fork of parent and every time I commit to parent, I merge into child.

The problem is that parent isn't constant, so parent and child evolve over time and at any given moment, parent may have the following features: (*feature-1, feature-2, feature-4*) and child, the following features: (*feature-1, feature-2, feature-3, feature-4, feature-5*). And in some cases, I end up with merge conflicts.

What architecture would you suggest to avoid such conflicts in the future please ?

Comment: Maybe not so much architecture, but the best strategy to make conflicts less likely is to write code so that it is [orthogonal](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/122625/11110).